# react bootstrap: how to send form from modal buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Here is hierarchy of my components

```
class MyDialog extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        children: PropTypes.node,
        show: PropTypes.bool
    };

    onClick() {
        // submit form
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal show={this.props.show}>
                <Modal.Body>
                    {this.props.children}
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={::this.onClick}>Submit</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}    

class MyForm extends Component {

    onSubmit() {
        // ajax call
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Form onSubmit={::this.onSubmit}/>
        );
    }
}

class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        <MyDialog show={true}>
            <MyForm>
        </MyDialog>
    }
}
```

I wonder what is the proper way to send form using button from modal dialog

Also its possible I want to reuse dialog for some other content not a form

Comment: Any answer/suggestion ? I'm interested in this question...

Comment: See http://www.webpackbin.com/EyB6usAOz